# PHP Fatal error: Unable to start pcre module in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, pcre, php-7.4

When i run php command in terminal getting this error

**PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start pcre module in Unknown on line 0**

I have php7.4 installed and tried to install external pcre from https://www.pcre.org/. 
After restart server i got his error and now cannot start apache2 as well

[image]

Comment: Did you build your own PHP [following these instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php)?

Comment: Hi Chris, I installed it with `sudo apt install php7.4` command. I did not use any 
`--with-pcre-regex=DIR` or `--without-pcre-jit`

Comment: I removed all **libpcre**  .so files from **/usr/local/lib** and after that it's working fine. 
`cd /usr/local/lib` 
`rm libpcre*`